# jQuery how to offset the position between 2 or more elements through its current position

Tags: jquery, position

[image]

I want to have the lime green's right edge line up with the right edge of the darker green. I know the element will need to be fixed position. But i am trying to figure out how I can get the edges and then use them to my advantage of finding what the offset to the position left would be to move it over.

initially tried something like

```
    var parWidth = $theElement.parent().width;
    var parLeft = $theElement.parent().position().left;
    var moveToLeft = Math.round((parWidth - $theElement.width) - parLeft);
```

but its returning NaN, finding the width, left of both the parent element (dark green) and the child element (lime) is not the issue, I think its my math, and my logic currently on how to do the math correctly. The reason I am doing this dynamically like I am is cause I have multiple elements that all share the same classes to trigger this event, but I am making the function dynamic to the specific element thats triggering the events, and its all working up to that point.

***EDIT***
The HTML:

```
<div class="button_select_header_like_thing">
    <div class="button_select">
        <ul class="button_select_toggle" id="button_groupings">
            <li>
                <div class="button_select_text">Menu Text</div><div class="button_select_arrow">V</div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="button_select_sub" rel="hidden">
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                </ul>       
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JS code to:

```
var parWidth = $theElement.parent().width(); // width is a function, not a property
var parLeft = $theElement.parent().position().left;
var moveToLeft = Math.round((parWidth - $theElement.width()) - parLeft);
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating dropdown menus, it's always more advisable to put the children `ul` elements as direct children of the parent `li` item, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent 1</li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This helps you manipulate the children (hiding, showing, styling, etc.) a lot easier. In that light, check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MEPm9/) which I built on your original code where the children line up with the parents exactly, simply by assigning them a width of `100%`, effectively hitting the edges set out by the parents.

Here's the code for everyone scared of jsfiddle (HTML first):

```
<div class="button_select_header_like_thing">
    <div class="button_select">
        <ul class="button_select_toggle" id="button_groupings">
            <li class="li_parent">
                <div class="button_select_text">Menu Text</div>
                <div class="button_select_arrow">V</div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <ul class="button_select_sub" rel="hidden">
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                    <li>Text</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and then the CSS:

```
.li_parent
{
    width: 200px;
}

.button_select_text
{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: GREEN;
}

.button_select_arrow
{
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: GREEN;
}

.li_parent ul
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ORANGE;
}
```

Hope this helps, or even just gives you something to think about! :)